# Serialize complex properties with Dapper

Tags: dapper

Is it possible to make Dapper.NET serialize complex properties with Json.NET? The object should be serialized and then stored into a column as string:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; } // store this as string in database
    ...
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Right now we do this manually using ADO.NET:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", obj.Id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", obj.Address != null ? JsonConvert.Serialize(obj.Address) : (object) DBNull.Value);
...
```

Comment: This scenario is not supported currently.

Comment: Did you ever find a Dapper work-around for this?

Comment: is this feature included in dapper?

Comment: Have you considered using `SqlMapper.ITypeHandler` to create custom data conversion?